# Can be professional with Drupal without having the Knowledge of PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

Can be professional with Drupal without having the Knowledge of PHP

and do something like Create a new custom theme .. etc or anything

actually I have a very little bit knowledge with php

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For site administration; You don't need PHP knowledge to administrate and build a Drupal site.

For building custom themes; Your limited PHP knowledge will help you build basic custom theme.

For making custom modules; I don't believe you can do that with limited PHP knowledge. It'd  be much better if you could extend your PHP knowledge level.